# What are SERVICE_AUTH_URL and SERVICE_AUTH_TOKEN_URL in Gmail Add-ons?

Tags: google-apps-script, add-on, gmail-addons

This is Google's code

```
 function getOAuthService() {
 return OAuth2.createService('SERVICE_NAME')
      .setAuthorizationBaseUrl('SERVICE_AUTH_URL')
      .setTokenUrl('SERVICE_AUTH_TOKEN_URL')
      .setClientId('CLIENT_ID')
      .setClientSecret('CLIENT_SECRET')
      .setScope('SERVICE_SCOPE_REQUESTS')
      .setCallbackFunction('authCallback')
      .setCache(CacheService.getUserCache())
      .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties());
}
```

I don't know what are SERVICE_AUTH_URL and  SERVICE_AUTH_TOKEN_URL

This is my

```
var SERVICE_AUTH_URL = 'http://account.simontest.com/a/login?app=addon';
```

After submit and login, I redirect my website to this link: 
https://script.google.com/macros/d/13-mVZUel3ZnYoFKC5JrRUkWD12iMSa3REEfddfdf71ucXm1rA_s0/usercallback
and got this message :

"Sorry, unable to open the file at this time.

Please check the address and try again."
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Gm1Q.jpg

But It's still error.
Anybody has any idea about where I am going wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Anybody has any idea about where I am going wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here, SERVICE_AUTH_TOKEN_URL is the rest api url of the service to get the access token, refresh token using auth code generated in the oauth login process. Probably, you might have missed the callback implementation.Follow the below code:

```js
var oauthService = getOAuthService();

function authCallback(oauthResponse) {
  try {
    console.log("oauthResponse->" + JSON.stringify(oauthResponse));
    oauthService.handleCallback(oauthResponse);
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("auth-success");
  } catch (e) {
    var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("auth-failure");
    template.errorMessage = e.toString();
    return template.evaluate();
  }
}
```

**auth-success.html:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="sidebar">
        <p>Your GitHub account has been connected.</p>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script>
  setTimeout(function() {
    top.window.close();
  }, 2000);
  </script>
</html>
```

**auth-failure.html:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="sidebar">
      <p>Your GitHub account was not connected. Please try again.</p>
      <h3>Details:</h3>
      <pre><?= errorMessage ?></pre>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I kept getting the "Sorry, unable to open the file at this time." message until I realized you have to append a secret access code as well as the state to the url.

The OAuth2 server (account.simontest.com in your case) needs to format the redirect url like this:

Pseudo-code:

```
$redirect_uri = $redirect_uri . "?code=" . $your_secret_code . "&state=" . $state
```

See this page for more details: [OAuth2 Simplified](https://aaronparecki.com/oauth-2-simplified/)